# Select rows where column value is a combination of numbers and letters

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Having a dataset like this:

```
    word
0   TBH46T
1   BBBB
2   5AAH
3   CAAH
4   AAB1
5   5556
```

Which would be the most efficient way to select the rows where column **word** is a combination of numbers and letters?

The output would be like this:

```
    word    
0   TBH46T      
2   5AAH        
4   AAB1
```

A possible solution would be to create a new column using **apply** and **regex** in which store if column **word** has the desired structure. But I'm curious about if this could be achieved in a more straightforward way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for chain mask for match numeric and for match non numeric with `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df = df[df['word'].str.contains('\d') & df['word'].str.contains('\D')]
print (df)
     word
0  TBH46T
2    5AAH
4    AAB1
```